# SQL query to find employee aniversary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to  find anniversary date and anniversary year of employees and send email in every 14 days.But I have a problem with last week of December when using the following query if start date and end date are in different years.

```
    Select * from Resource
    where (DATEPART(dayofyear,JoinDate)
    BETWEEN DATEPART(dayofyear,GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(dayofyear,DateAdd(DAY,14,GETDATE())))
```

Comment: How do you treat the join date on 29th Feb?

Comment: @Eric - it doesn't just fail for 29th February - it fails for any situation where the current year and the year of joining aren't either both leap years or both non-leap years (for dates in March and beyond)

Comment: Select *,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE()) as [Years],DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE()),JoinDate) as [AnniversaryDate]  from Resource
where (DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,joinDate,GetDate()),JoinDate) 
BETWEEN '2015-12-25'
AND DATEADD(Day,14,'2015-12-25')
OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,joinDate,'2015-12-25')+1,JoinDate) -- 2016-1-1
BETWEEN '2015-12-25' 
AND DATEADD(Day,14,'2015-12-25')) AND IsActive = 1 AND IsCurrentEmployee =1 AND JDisplayName NOT  LIKE '0%' order by AnniversaryDate
Select DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,'2015-12-25'),JoinDate) as [AnniversaryDate]  from Resource

Comment: @ Jamiec : I enhanced code as shown above.Now [Years] and [AnniversaryDate] are one year less  than expected.

Comment: Please don't try to add code in comments - as you've probably observed, it doesn't work well. If you want to show more code, please *[edit]* your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of comparing to a `dayofyear` (which resets to zero at jan 1st and is the reason your query breaks within 14 days of the end of the year) you could update the employee's `joindate` to be the current year for the purpose of the query and just compare to actual dates

```
Select * from Resource
-- Add the number of years difference between joinDate and the current year
where DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,joinDate,GetDate()),JoinDate) 
-- compare to range "today"
BETWEEN GetDate()
-- to 14 days from today
AND DATEADD(Day,14,GetDate())
-- duplicate for following year
OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,joinDate,GetDate())+1,JoinDate) -- 2016-1-1
BETWEEN GetDate() 
AND DATEADD(Day,14,GetDate())
```

Test query:

```
declare @joindate DATETIME='2012-1-1'
declare @today DATETIME = '2015-12-26'

SELECT @joinDate 
where DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,@joinDate,@today),@JoinDate) -- 2015-1-1
BETWEEN @today -- 2015-12-26
AND DATEADD(Day,14,@today) -- 2016-01-09
OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,@joinDate,@today)+1,@JoinDate) -- 2016-1-1
BETWEEN @today -- 2015-12-26
AND DATEADD(Day,14,@today) -- 2016-01-09
```

(H/T @Damien_The_Unbeliever for a simple fix)

The above correctly selects the `joinDate` which is in the first week of Jan (note I've had to fudge `@today` as Ive not managed to invent time travel).

The above solution should also solve the issue with leap years that was hiding in your original solution.

---

**Update**

You expressed in comments the requirement to select `AnniversaryDate` and `Years` of service, you need to apply some `CASE` logic to determine whether to add 1 (year or date) to your select

```
select *,
CASE 
    WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE()),JoinDate) < GetDate()
    THEN DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE())+1
    ELSE DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE())
END as [Years],
CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE()),JoinDate) < GetDate()
    THEN DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE())+1,JoinDate) 
    ELSE DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE()),JoinDate) 
end as [AnniversaryDate] 
.... // etc
```

Comment: This query fails when joindate is '2012-1-1' and today is '2015-226'.

Comment: @submine - you editied that comment and now the date is not valid.

Comment: The simple way to address that issue is to add a second `BETWEEN` comparison, using the same endpoint values, but `DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,joinDate,GetDate())+1,JoinDate) 
BETWEEN ...` (i.e. recompute the `joinDate` for this year and for next year, and check whether either occurs within the next 14 days)

Comment: This query fails when joindate is '2012-1-1' and today is '2015-22-6'.

Comment: Beware of the GETDATE(), it is `datetime` not `date`, the query fail for today of last year, i.e. '2014-07-13'

Comment: @submine `2015-22-6` is not a valid date in this universe (what do you call the 22nd month in your universe ;))

Comment: This query fails when joindate is '2016-1-1' and today is '2015-12-26'

Comment: @submine see update, and thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever for a simple workaround

Comment: @ Jamiec Seems perfect and thanks a lot and appreciate helping mentality.

Comment: Select *,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE()) as [Years],DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE()),JoinDate) as [AnniversaryDate]  from Resource
where (DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,joinDate,GetDate()),JoinDate) 
BETWEEN '2015-12-25'
AND DATEADD(Day,14,'2015-12-25')
OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,joinDate,'2015-12-25')+1,JoinDate) -- 2016-1-1
BETWEEN '2015-12-25' 
AND DATEADD(Day,14,'2015-12-25')) AND IsActive = 1 AND IsCurrentEmployee =1 AND JDisplayName NOT  LIKE '0%' order by AnniversaryDate
Select DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,'2015-12-25'),JoinDate) as [AnniversaryDate]  from Resource

Comment: @ Jamiec : I enhanced code as shown above.Now [Years] and [AnniversaryDate] are one year less  than expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83126/discussion-between-submine-and-jamiec).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Select * from Resource
where DATEPART(dayofyear,JoinDate)
BETWEEN DATEPART(dayofyear,GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(dayofyear,DateAdd(DAY,14,GETDATE()))
OR
DATEPART(dayofyear,JoinDate)
BETWEEN (DATEPART(dayofyear,GETDATE()) + 365)
AND  (DATEPART(dayofyear,DateAdd(DAY,14,GETDATE())) + 365)
```

Comment: Select *,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE()) as [Years],DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,GETDATE()),JoinDate) as [AnniversaryDate]  from Resource
where (DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,joinDate,GetDate()),JoinDate) 
BETWEEN '2015-12-25'
AND DATEADD(Day,14,'2015-12-25')
OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(Year,joinDate,'2015-12-25')+1,JoinDate) -- 2016-1-1
BETWEEN '2015-12-25' 
AND DATEADD(Day,14,'2015-12-25')) AND IsActive = 1 AND IsCurrentEmployee =1 AND JDisplayName NOT  LIKE '0%' order by AnniversaryDate
Select DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(Year,JoinDate,'2015-12-25'),JoinDate) as [AnniversaryDate]  from Resource

Comment: @ Jamiec : I enhanced code as shown above.Now [Years] and [AnniversaryDate] are one year less  than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE() --'12/25/2013'
DECLARE @Duration INT = 14

;WITH Recur AS
(
    SELECT @Today AS RecurDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, RecurDate)
    FROM Recur
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, @Today, RecurDate)+1 < @Duration
)
SELECT
    r.*
FROM
    Resource r
    JOIN Recur 
        ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), JoinDate, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), RecurDate, 101)
WHERE JoinDate <  @Today
```

Comment: cant add integer to datetime

Comment: @submine - yes you can! It adds that number of days. (`select GetDate() + 14` today yields `2015-07-27 12:06:44.623`)

Comment: @ Jamiec You are Right

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [SQL DATEADD() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dateadd-function-tsql-example.aspx) with week number parameter
Here is how you can use it:

```
DECLARE @date date = getdate()
Select * from Resource
where
    JoinDate BETWEEN @date AND DATEADD(ww,2,@date)
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question